# Printing only one combination using nested loops

Tags: c, for-loop, codeblocks, combinations, nested-loops

I have to print combination of different currency notes a man should have to pay to the cashier. Program first ask total amount to be paid and then notes of different denominations that he possesses. The problem is, I have to print only one combination of currency notes, but I am getting all combinations (as usual) by the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int hundred,fifty,ten,total,hund,fif,t;
    printf ("Enter amount to be paid:");
    scanf ("%d",&total);
    printf ("\n\nHow many currency notes do you have?\nEnter 100,50 and 10 Rupee Notes Respectively:\n");
    scanf ("%d %d %d",&hund,&fif,&t);

    printf ("\t\t\tPossible combination for Rs=%d/- \n",total);

    for (hundred=0; hundred<=hund; hundred++)
    {
          for (fifty=0; fifty<=fif; fifty++)
        {
            for (ten=0; ten<=t; ten++)
            {
                if ((hundred*100+fifty*50+ten*10)==total)
                {
                    printf("\n\n Hundred rupees notes=%d, 50 rupees notes=%d, 10 rupees notes=%d",hundred,fifty,ten);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think how you can make it with no loops and less number of currency to be used

Comment: `printf` and `return 0;`

Comment: "The code is working perfectly" -- while cleaning up your indentation I found a stray `{`. Please make sure the code you use to show the problem is correct in itself.

Comment: @Pradheep I did it without any loop at all. But I am told by my instructor to try it with nesting.

Comment: @AsharNawazKhan , you can end the program or use `goto()` as mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for the correction. It was just because i was trying new things in it and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @shekharsuman Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `getch();` and `return 0;` just after the `printf` inside the nested loops.

Another way is to use `goto`. Type

```
goto exit;
```

Just after the `printf` inside the nested loops and type

```
exit:
```

Just before the `getch();`.